# SKProductsRequest returns not country specific prices for Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewable

I started getting the same prices in all countries for my Auto-Renewable Subscriptions though I configured different prices on per county basis in appstoreconnect.
It returns price for country where main development account was created
Seems it happens after applying new tax category, previously everything works flawlessly.
Have anyone else got the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was:

- on old device iOS 12 - it was using different sandbox account
- on iOS 14 relogin in "Media & Purchase" helped to fix issue